# Developing a scalable Twitter data adaptor

Tags: java, twitter, scalability

We are building a Twitter adaptor for our product platform to collect tweets using both Search API and Streaming
API. We have developed a prototype that uses Java Executor Service and Twitter4j to collect tweets and submit
them to our tweets queue.

Here are some design decisions we would request suggestions on:

1. How to make the adaptor client scalable and fault tolerant ?
2. How to prevent retrieving duplicate tweets ?
3. How to maximize retrieval of tweets using multiple user id without hitting the rate limit ?

Answer (score 1):

Some answers , but bare in mind it has been awhile since I used twitter API - 
In order to make the adaptor scalable and fault tolerant you can consider the following techniques -

1. Use several instances (i.e - clustering) of your client-  it really depends what it does, but you may decide to use an Active-Active or Active-Passive clustering model
2. If you go for clustering - Do you have clients connecting to the adapter? If so , you will need a load balancer that supports sticky session (so during a given session, a client addresses the same Adapter instance) - check [this][1] link for some info.
3. I recommend you use caching for twitts - and if we look at a cache as map of key to value, and then your key can probably the URL that you use in order to get the information from Twitter API (If I recall, the API is some sort of a RESTful web service) 
    You should set eviction policies on the cache (i.e - how long the data is considered relevant for you) - this may help you both in performance, and both to reduce the number of accesses to twitter (I'm referring you to the part of your question about the rate limit).
4. Maybe you should see if you can share information between users - but this will have some logic involved. 
    An example - if user A follows user B, and B follows A, they might have more common followers or users they follow, and you can share data.
5. If you go for clustering as I suggested before, your cache should be distributed. You can use [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-topologies) for this
6. If you store information at database - try to minimize data base accesses, by building a thread local bases caching system (so within a thread, if you perform twice get on the same ID for the same entity, without a write, you will not access the database twice...)

In conclusion, this is just a tip of an iceberg for advice, you should carefully understand your requirements , uses cases and flows, and see how you can optimize each one of them.